# Terminate after single validation error - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know it is somewhere in the documentation, but I can't find it. How can I output one validation error at a time instead of aggregating over every possible validation and output everything in $entity->errors()? In addition to that, is there a simple way to give this setting to every validation in every table?

**Edit**

I already found the answer to the first question which  is the following:

```
$validator
->add('body', [
    'minLength' => [
        'rule' => ['minLength', 10],
        'last' => true, // this particular line
        'message' => 'Comments must have a substantial body.'
    ],
    'maxLength' => [
        'rule' => ['maxLength', 250],
        'message' => 'Comments cannot be too long.'
    ]
]);
```

Again, is there any way to apply this to all validation methods, everywhere?